# Pytorch input tensor is correct data type, but throws RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Long but got scalar type Float for argument #3

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am trying to write a simple CNN using PyTorch, but am getting an error in my first layer. The following lines of code will produce the error `RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Long but got scalar type Float for argument #3 'mat1' in call to _th_addmm_`, despite me setting the input to type Long. The print statement in the 3rd line also gives `torch.LongTensor`, yet the fourth line still throws the error.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

data = torch.randint(low=0, high=255, size=[2, 1, 1024, 1024], dtype=torch.int64)
model = nn.Conv2d(1, 3, kernel_size=3, padding=1, bias=False)
print(data.type())
out = model(data)
```

Comment: I think the convolutional layer requires the inputs to be floating point, not integers. Usually, you can convert a integer-valued image into float point by scaling each pixel to be between 0 and 1 (i.e., divide by 255.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of your data is `Long`, but the type of the `weights` of your model is `Float`. You need to change the type of your data if you are planning to train a model:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

data = torch.randint(low=0, high=255, size=[2, 1, 1024, 1024], dtype=torch.float32)
model = nn.Conv2d(1, 3, kernel_size=3, padding=1, bias=False)
print(data.type())
out = model(data)
```